# Sending raw Body JSON to AWS Lambda via API gateway

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have been struggling with API Gateway trying to get what I assumed would be a simple procedure, sending raw JSON from a webhook to my AWS Lambda as an event to use within my function.

All I want to do is output the Woocommerce order number and send an email of the order number as well by getting the Woocommerce webhook body to Lambda, like I have in my test event. Here is the function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new AWS.SES();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

// Send email to customer via Amazon SES with url link of TXT transcription file on S3
var eParams = {Destination: {ToAddresses: ["flla@isdaq.com"]}, Message: {Body: { Text: { Data: event.number },},Subject: { Data: 'TITLE' }}, Source: "ses@eucommission.trade"};
var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function (err, data) { if (err) console.log(err); else { console.log("===EMAIL SENT==="); } });
console.log('Woocommerce Order Number is: ', event.number); // successful response

};
```

If I place some Woocommerce webhook into the test area in Lambda it works fine. But if I place an order in Woocommerce,nothing happens

Here is what I have done so far:

- Setup API Gateway linked to my AWS Lambda and placed that API URL within a Woocommerce webhook as a target URL when an order is created
- Setup a POST method in API Gateway, *Integration Request* using the code below and  *Integration Response* has not been edited

  {
      "method": "$context.httpMethod",
      "body" : $input.json('$'),
      "headers": {
          #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
          "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))"
          #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
          #end
      }
  }
- Enabled CORS for POST in the API Gateway console

[image: Lambda Test Event]

[image: Woocommerce webhook to RequestBin]

Can anyone help me crack this. I have crawled the web, Stack O and tried numerous things for hours.

Comment: this may be a silly question but have you deployed your API?

Comment: Yep, API is deployed. Always after any changes too.

Comment: Have you tried to simply log the event paramter to check if there are any differences?