# Send an ajax request in javascript to AWS API Gateway using raw body

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, postman, aws-api-gateway

The following body can be successfully sent to an AWS API Gateway, using Body -> Raw in Postman

```
{
    "toEmails": ["foo@example.com"],
    "subject": "test email from Postman",
    "message": "Hello World!"
}
```

How do I adjust the following JQuery snippet to send the request to the same API Gateway?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(res){
                console.log('Email was sent.');
            },
            error: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632041/sending-raw-body-json-to-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html